# what are the differences of Inheritance & java Beans?

Tags: java

What are the differences between Inheritance & JavaBeans?

Comment: If you're trying to compare inheritance and JavaBeans, you're comparing apples with squids (not even oranges). :-P

Comment: It ain't the same ballpark, it ain't the same league, hell, it ain't even the same f*ckin' sport

Comment: I was trying to think of a similarity, but came up blank.

Comment: I think you guys are being too harsh on this question. One of the first results for "difference between Java Beans and EJBs" on google says that Java Beans are "Basically used to CUSTOMIZE EXISTING OBJECTS" and not much else. Coming from a vague definition like that, this question sounds quite reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

Inheritance is a general object oriented programming concept whereby one type can be of the same type as another object but introduce new properties and behaviors (i.e. a Lion class could inherit from a Mammal class) while JavaBeans are just Java objects that adhere to a set of conventions. From Wikipedia:

> - The class must have a public default constructor. This allows easy
>     instantiation within editing and
>     activation frameworks.
> - The class properties must be accessible using get, set, and other
>     methods (so-called accessor methods
>     and mutator methods), following a
>     standard naming convention. This
>     allows easy automated inspection and
>     updating of bean state within
>     frameworks, many of which include
>     custom editors for various types of
>     properties.
> - The class should be serializable. This allows applications and
>     frameworks to reliably save, store,
>     and restore the bean's state in a
>     fashion that is independent of the VM
>     and platform.

Comment: Good answer to a bad question!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean, but when people talk about beans vs. inheritance it usually means naming convention vs. inheritance.

Bean defines it's properties using matching get and set methods, and also optionally using BeanInfo, so the properties are then accessed using introspection (reflection). When objects extends a class or implements an interface, on the other hand, the properties/methods are accessed via that interface (superclass).

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

A Java Bean is a simple class which contains some properties (i.e. data elements) and "getters and setters" (getProperty1(), setProperty1(myValue)) to read and write those properties.

Inheritance is an Object Oriented principle in which one class exhibits the properties and behaviours of another. It is said to **inherit** from the other class.

Comment: "principle", you mean, not principal.